# I am having CORS error with HEROKU app, sending a request from github page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, cors, gatsby

I've created a small `nodejs` app for mailing purpose and deployed it on `heroku`.

My frontend has a contact form and it is hosted using github pages.
I've enabled `cors` on my backend but still when I submit form, I get `cors` error.

Here is piece of code from my backend.

```js
const express = require("express");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS, PUT"
  );
  next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/contact", (req, res, next) => {
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",...
```

and my request on frontend looks like this.

```js
const submitHandler = e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  if (formState.formIsValid) {
    setIsSending(true)
    axios
      .post("https://portfolio-kk-mail.herokuapp.com/contact",
        {
          sender: formState.inputValues.email,
          subject: formState.inputValues.subject,
          message: formState.inputValues.message,
        },
        {
          headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        }
      )
      .then(res => {
         setIsSending(false)
         setError(false)
         submitBtn.current.style.background =
           "linear-gradient(to right, #4BB543, #4BB54344)"
         submitBtn.current.style.border = "1px solid #4BB543"
      })
      .catch(err => {
        setIsSending(false)
        setError(true)
        submitBtn.current.style.border = "1px solid #B00020"
        submitBtn.current.style.background =
         "linear-gradient(to right, #B00020, #B0002044)"
      })
   }
}
```

I dont have a clue, what am I missing?

Comment: Hmm, it looks fine. Can you kindly attach the exact CORS errror generated.

Comment: Try adding a handler for `app.options('/contact', (req, res) => res.status(200).end())`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are setting the content-type to be JSON, your CORS request automatically becomes a preflighted request.  The only content-types that don't require pre-flight are:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
multipart/form-data
text/plain
```

Because the browser classifies your request as a preflighted request, it will send an OPTIONS request to your server to check if the request is allowed.  You will need a handler for that on your server.

```
app.options('/contact', (req, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(204);
});
```

Just place this after your CORS middleware.

---

You can read about the criteria for [Simple Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests) that are not pre-flighted and you can read about [Preflighted Rquests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests) in those references on MDN.

Comment: I did, it still doesn't work.

Do I need to change Content-Type?

Comment: @codyzcode - We would have to see the exact error in Chrome and perhaps the network  trace of what the browser is doing in order to advise further.  If it is possible to remove the reasons your request is a preflighted request so that it becomes a simple request, then that would probably fix it.  If it needs to stay a preflighted request in order to do what it needs to do, then you will have to look at the back and forth between the browser and your server and see exactly what's going on between the two.